# What logic is used behind this accelerometer sensor listener

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, shake, android-sensors

This is the code i am using to capture the shake of the phone:

```
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor mySensor = event.sensor;
        if (mySensor.getType() == SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {
            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // only allow one update every 100ms.
            if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
                long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
                lastUpdate = curTime;

                x = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
                y = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
                z = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];

                float speed = Math.abs(x+y+z - last_x - last_y - last_z)/ diffTime * 10000;
                if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD_HIGH) {
                    // yes, this is a shake action! Do something about it!
                    handshake_score.setText(String.valueOf(speed));
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(Handshake.this)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                    .setTitle("noo")
                    .setMessage("too much") 
                    .setPositiveButton("OK!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                    .show();

                    last_x = x;
                    last_y = y;
                    last_z = z;

                } else if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD_PASS) {
                    // yes, this is a shake action! Do something about it!
                    handshake_score.setText(String.valueOf(speed));
                    sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this);
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(Handshake.this)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                    .setTitle("HAHAA!")
                    .setMessage("good") 
                    .setPositiveButton("OK!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                    .show();

                    finish();

                } else if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD_SMALL) {
                    // yes, this is a shake action! Do something about it!
                    handshake_score.setText(String.valueOf(speed));
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(Handshake.this)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                    .setTitle("boo")
                    .setMessage("not enough") 
                    .setPositiveButton("OK!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                    .show();

                    last_x = x;
                    last_y = y;
                    last_z = z;
                }
                last_x = x;
                last_y = y;
                last_z = z;
            }
        }           
  }
```

What i want to do is imitate a handshake so it would respond to lifting the phone up and down when holding it horizontally as if you`re facing the landscape screen and moving it up and down.

While this code resopnds to twisting the phone as if you spin the phone around its length axis.

Can someone explain the logics behind coordinates x, y and z used in this code, where are these in terms of place in the phone and how i could have the phoen responding to "handshakes" rather then twisting it in your hand.

any ideas for such code?

Answer (score 0):

add this in your activity class

```
/* put this into your activity class */
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private float mAccel; // acceleration apart from gravity
private float mAccelCurrent; // current acceleration including gravity
private float mAccelLast; // last acceleration including gravity

private final SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
  float x = se.values[0];
  float y = se.values[1];
  float z = se.values[2];
  mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
  mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
  float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
  mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}
 };

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
 mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,   mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),   SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
super.onStop();
}
```

And add this to your onCreate method:

```
 mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,    mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
mAccel = 0.00f;
mAccelCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
mAccelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
```

i hope this will help